# Using PHPunit for a webapplication

Tags: phpunit

So, I'm using Junit for Java and I've gotten convinsed of the benefit of TDD. Now I'm working (with a team) on a webapplication for my boss (html/css/php) and proposed to write some tests in PHPunit for the WA. But I can't find any way the code processes data (but the WA does work so far). I started google-ing and found only tutorials who work with functions in the code to test.

My question is: is it even possible to use PHPunit for testing the php-code from between the html-lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about functional testing rather than unit testing. [Codeception](https://codeception.com/) (built on top of PHPUnit) might be a good place to start for you, since it has more natural functional testing out of the box.

Some example:

- https://codeception.com/docs/02-GettingStarted
- https://codeception.com/docs/03-AcceptanceTests